# Find numbers of nodes between root and give node

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

So in a given binary tree (node binary search tree), initially I want to find the number of nodes between two nodes "p" and "q". I first find the lowest common ancestor between these two nodes, say, "ancestor". Then I calculate the number of nodes between "ancestor" and "p" and number of nodes between "ancestor" and "q" separately and add them at last.

I tried recursive way to get number of nodes between "ancestor" and "p" or "q" but failed. Not a fan of recursive.

```
public static int NodeToNodePath(BinaryTree root, BinaryTree node, int length){

    if(root == null && node == null)
        return 0;

    if(root == null || node == null)
        return 0;

    if(root.rootElement == node.rootElement){
        return length;
    }

    int sum = NodeToNodePath(root.left, node, length + 1);
    if(sum != 0)
        return sum;

    sum = NodeToNodePath(root.right, node, sum);
    return sum;

}
```

But in this way, the result from root to left mode is correct but can't find node on the other size.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have a method to calculate the deepness level of a node ? For example if the common ancestor is 3 levels deep, left is 5 and right is 7, the distance will be (5-3) + (7-5)

Comment: No, I don't have that method. But now I'm stuck on finding the number of nodes between the root and specific node.

Comment: Why do you need the first `if` if you have the second one?  And if you know that "p" and "q" are in the tree, why do you need either?

Comment: Shouldn't there be something that decides between following the left or right subtree to get from `root` to `node`?  Basically as searching a BST (which you've already done once, so this seems redundant).

Comment: I need the first cause for the function it only takes the "root", two nodes "p" and "q" as input. But the path between "p" and "q" doesn't have to go through the root. That's why first I need to find the lowest common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to solve the problem. By recursion. This may not apply to my origin problem 
"find node number between two given nodes" but it does return number of nodes between root and a given node.

Code is posted below. 
    public static int NodeToNodePath(BinaryTree root,
            BinaryTree node, int length) {
        if(root == null)
            return 0;

```
    if(root.rootElement == node.rootElement){
        length += 1;
        return length;
    }


    int left = NodeToNodePath(root.left, node, length);
    if(left != 0){
        return left + 1;
    }

    int right = NodeToNodePath(root.right, node, length);
    if(right != 0){
        return right + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I found a post on GeekForGeeks talking specifically about my origin problem, it's called "Find distance between two given keys of a Binary Tree" the address is:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-distance-two-given-nodes/

Thanks everyone!